# Angular routerLink with automatic href

Tags: angular, routes, href, anchor, routerlink

In my Angular application I have a lot of buttons which navigate to a different location (navigation bar, etc.). As I have a single-page application (SPA) this is of course simulated by Angular.

Currently I am using the `[routerLink]` directive for routing which works fine. Now I would like my buttons to behave more like *real* links, e.g. `ctrl + righ click` should open the link in a new tab and right clicking should show the context menu of a normal anchor link:

[image]

But of course I still want the application to stay a SPA and not reload whenever a link is clicked. Is there a best practice for achieving this? I found the [RouterLinkWithHref](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkWithHref) directive but I don't know if this has anything to do with it.

A workaround which does the trick is setting both the `routerLink` and the `href` directive.

```html
<a routerLink="/" href="/"><button mat-stroked-button>Back to dashboard</button><a>
```

[image]

Which adds the not-so-pretty link styling and feels very redundant.
Of course this could be combined in a custom directive but I feel like the use case I am describing here is very common and should therefore have a clear solution.

Is there a reason why it's not the default behavior of a `routerLink` to show the context action like it is a *real* link?
And what is the best practice for transforming elements with a `routerLink` to elements that behave like *real* links (I would like to have all the router buttons, list-items etc. in my application to appear like normal links)?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this in my various angular applications in this way

```
<a href="javascript:;" routerLink="/about-us">About us</a>
```

Still not sure if it is the right practice or not but works fine for me with functions like ctrl+click or right click.

Comment: Nice, quite simple. Do you know why it works? And also do you use this for buttons or just links in the applications? I am kind of looking for best practices here.

Answer (score 0):

Using the RouterLink Directive on a link (`a` tag) along with the `href` should be all you need to do. For internal links, the RouterLink Directive should add the `href` attribute to the link without it needing to be added manually.

```
<a routerLink="/about-us">About us</a>
```

should become the following when rendered:

```
<a href="/about-us" routerLink="/about-us">About us</a>
```

The RouterLink Directive doesn't seem to add an `href` attribute automatically for external links, and I haven't dug into it to figure out exactly sure why. In that case, your mentioned solution is the "correct" one, IMO, and there isn't anything wrong with adding both the href attribute and the routerLink directive.

```
<a href="https://example.com/about-us" routerLink="/about-us">About us</a>
```

IMO, this is a much better option as compared to using the `href="javascript:;"` option, as it will better behave like a standard link.